# SQL вытащить значение из строки

Tags: sql

подскажите как правильно вытащить значение из строки в select

к примеру есть поле
`text  {"cod":"1", "fio":"Иванов Иван", "desc":"какое-то описание ...."}`
мне нужно в `select` вместо
`{"cod":"1...", "fio":"Иванов Иван", "desc":"какое-то описание ...."}`
получить `Иванов Иван`

MYSQL - 5.7

Comment: А после какого типа ? если json, то `text->>'$.fio'`

Comment: А если текстовое - то воспользоваться json_extract

Comment: спасибо большое и первый и второй вариант рабочий